# How do I use .populate with .findOne in an Express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm in the process of learning Node, Mongoose and Express by trying to build a CRUD API. When trying to "join" two MongoDB collections with the .populate function, I get an error that

*db.collection(...).findOne(...).populate is not a function*

My javascript chops are not great, so I've tried rewriting this in different ways to no avail.

**server.js**

```
require('./models/User')
require('./models/Product')

var db 

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://<username>:</password>@xxxx.mlab.com:xxx/xxx', (err, database) => {
if (err) return console.log(err)
    db = database
    app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log("listening on port 3000");
    })
})

app.get('/api/users/:id', (req, res) => {
db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).findOne({ id: (req.params.id) }).populate('product'), (err, doc) => {
    if (err) handleError(res, err.message, 'Failed to get user')

    res.status(200).json(doc)   
    console.log(req.params)
 }
})
```

**models/user.js**

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')

 var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 id: String,
 first_name: String,
 last_name: String
 id: {
 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: 'Product'
 }
})

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Comment: Which node module is `db`?

Comment: If you are using Mongoose then you can use schema methods so you should be able to use `.populate` on a model object

Comment: @Sangharsh I've added how i'm setting up the db to the top of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections don't have the mongoose's model API including `.populate`. Instead of using collections directly, you should use the model that you registered in mongoose.

```js
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(...);

var User = mongoose.model('User', schema);
// you can also get the model after it was registered via mongoose.model('User')

app.get('/api/users/:id', (req, res) => {
User.findOne({ id: (req.params.id) }).populate('product'), (err, doc) => {
    if (err) handleError(res, err.message, 'Failed to get user')

    res.status(200).json(doc)   
    console.log(req.params)
 }
})
```

Comment: great, I'll try this out. my initial error is "User is not defined", so I assume my schema is not set up correctly. I'll look into that now. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are getting this error simply because you didn't define the variable in this exact file. Use `var User = mongoose.model('User')` (or whatever the name you registered the schema under).

Comment: i added what I believe are the other relevant snippets to my initial post. I appreciate your help

Comment: Just adding `var User = mongoose.model('User')` right after `var db` should make it work.

Comment: I'm not getting the error anymore, but I'm not getting the result I expect. A good problem to have. On the right track...thanks for the help!